# fopen64/ fseeko64 and c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, fopen

Im writing a code in c++ with codeblocks. I included the flag : " get g++ follow c++ 11.." In the compiler settings  to use chrono class, but after i included this flag i couldent compile the program because suddenly the function fopen64 "was not declared in the scope". Just so you know- i can compile the program without the flag.
How can i use both fopen64 and chrono class? Is this possible? And if not, is there other precise time measurement class so i can use to mesure microseconds? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answered easily. What OS are you using? Why are you using fopen64? Can you just use `fopen` and `fseek` instead?

Comment: im using windows 10. 
no i cant use fopen because i have to open large txt/dat files (40 GB and bigger....)

Comment: On Windows, you can use `_fseeki64()` and `_ftelli64()`.

Comment: If you're compiling a 64-bit application then `fopen` should use 64-bit offsets anyway, so isn't limited to 4GB files and you don't need to use `fopen64`. Are you sure you can't just use `fopen`?

Comment: hey, i added #define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE to my code but it can not read the file with fopen. my induction is - if i can print the characters of the file... if i use fopen it prints 0, but if i use fopen64 it prints the right number. my windows is 64-bit , does it mean that all the apps that i make run in 64-bit? if so, it still not working... more over - _fseeki64() is not declared, do i need to include somthing?

Comment: Which compiler are you using from code::blocks? Are you targeting win32 or win64?

Answer (score 4):

The `fopen64()` function is from the Linux Large File Support library.  It’s just a version of `fopen()` that supports files larger than 2Gbi.  On a modern system, you can use the standard library function, `fopen()`.  On Posix, you can use `fseeko()` and `ftello()` and on Windows, `_fseeki64()` and `_ftelli64()`.  That said, defining `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` might work on your compiler.

Comment: hey, 
i added #define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE to my code but it can not read the file with fopen. my induction is - if i can print the characters of the file... if i use fopen it prints 0, but if i use fopen64 it prints the right number. my windows is 64-bit , does it mean that all the apps that i make run in 64-bit? if so, it still not working... more over - _fseeki64() is not declared, do i need to include somthing?

Comment: @Noam Chai: If `#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE` and using `fopen64()` work for you, then do that.

Comment: But i cant use both chrono and fopen64 .. This is my original question.. Why when i check the flag, suddenly the function fopen64 is not declared in the scope??

Comment: Does fopen64() work with _LARGEFILE_SOURCE?  If not, _open() might.